# How to decode hex into separate bits in Perl?

Tags: perl, flags

A byte stored as two hex numbers contains a set of flags. I need to extract these flags, as 0's and 1's. Iterating over entries in a file with:

```
foreach(<>)
{
@line = split(/ /,$_);

$torR = !!((hex $line[4]) & 0x3);  # bit 0 or 1
$torY = !!((hex $line[4]) & 0x4);  # bit 2
$torG = !!((hex $line[4]) & 0x8);  # bit 3

print "$torR,$torY,$torG\n";
}
```

run on data file:

```
796.129 [1f/01] len:7<  02 01 D5 01 8B 0A 8E
796.224 [1f/01] len:7<  02 01 D4 03 09 A9 B8
796.320 [1f/01] len:7<  00 01 D4 03 07 49 5A
796.415 [1f/01] len:7<  00 01 D4 00 11 A0 EE
796.515 [1f/01] len:7<  00 01 D4 00 00 31 4C
796.627 [1f/01] len:7<  02 01 D4 01 89 C1 FD
796.724 [1f/01] len:7<  02 01 D3 03 06 39 FD
796.820 [1f/01] len:7<  08 01 D4 03 08 40 6F
796.915 [1f/01] len:7<  08 01 D5 00 13 3D A4
797.015 [1f/01] len:7<  08 01 D4 00 00 34 04
```

Actual Result -

```
1,,
1,,
,,
,,
,,
1,,
1,,
,,1
,,1
,,1
```

Desired result:

```
1,0,0
1,0,0
0,0,0
0,0,0
0,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
```

Seems like 'false' gets stored as empty string instead of '0'.

Is there a neat trick to get this right at once, or do I need to convert empty strings to zeros "manually"?

Comment: I'd do it _manually_ with `$torR = !!((hex $line[4]) & 0x3) || 0;`.

Comment: Please explain what you want to do. You're going about it the wrong way, but you don't say what you're trying to achieve so it's hard to help you. Please give some data so that we can run your code ourselves.

Comment: @Borodin: Added "desired result".

Comment: @SF: That doesn't let me run your code. You presumably have a loop of some sort going on, and you don't give any sample input. Please take a look at [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `+0` or `*1` could do.

Comment: @Сухой27: Not really. $torG will be 0 or 8, instead of 0 or 1.

Comment: @Borodin: Okay, complete example. What is the wrong way I'm going about it?

Comment: @SF 1. `foreach(<>)` You are slurping the file only to process it line by line. 2. You forgot to assign to `$line`, and 3. You don't coerce true/false to numeric. 4. `split / /` and `split ' '` do different things. You probably want `split ' '`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the true/false values to be numeric, you need to coerce them to be numeric:

```
$torR = 0 + !!((hex $line[4]) & 0x3);  # bit 0 or 1
$torY = 0 + !!((hex $line[4]) & 0x4);  # bit 2
$torG = 0 + !!((hex $line[4]) & 0x8);  # bit 3
```

Keep in mind that the empty string `''` is also a false value.

On the other hand, I might be inclined to write that as:

```
my (@ryg) = map 0 + !!((hex $line[4]) & $_), 0x3, 0x4, 0x5;
print join(', ', @ryg), "\n";
```

In addition, you would probably benefit from not using plain numbers in your program. Consider, for example, having a `%FLAG` structure that gives names to these constants, and a `%COL` structure that gives names to the columns you are interested in. Using the data you posted:

```
use Const::Fast;

const my %FLAG => (
    torR => 0x3,
    torY => 0x4,
    torG => 0x5,
);

const my %COL => (
    # ...
    tor => 4,
);

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    my @line = split ' ', $line;
    my %set_flags = map +($_ => 0 + !!((hex $line[$COL{tor}]) & $FLAG{$_})), qw(torR torY torG);
    print join(', ', @set_flags{qw(torR torY torG)}), "\n";
}

__DATA__
796.129 [1f/01] len:7<  02 01 D5 01 8B 0A 8E
796.224 [1f/01] len:7<  02 01 D4 03 09 A9 B8
796.320 [1f/01] len:7<  00 01 D4 03 07 49 5A
796.415 [1f/01] len:7<  00 01 D4 00 11 A0 EE
796.515 [1f/01] len:7<  00 01 D4 00 00 31 4C
796.627 [1f/01] len:7<  02 01 D4 01 89 C1 FD
796.724 [1f/01] len:7<  02 01 D3 03 06 39 FD
796.820 [1f/01] len:7<  08 01 D4 03 08 40 6F
796.915 [1f/01] len:7<  08 01 D5 00 13 3D A4
797.015 [1f/01] len:7<  08 01 D4 00 00 34 04
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would use `split` and `unpack` to turn each value into an array of zeroes and ones, and then examine them individually

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

for my $val ( qw/ 02 02 00 00 00 01 01 08 08 08 / ) {

    my @bits = split //, unpack 'b8', chr hex $val;

    my $torR = $bits[0] || $bits[1] ? 1 : 0;
    my $torY = $bits[2] ? 1 : 0;
    my $torG = $bits[3] ? 1 : 0;

    print "$torR,$torY,$torG\n";
}
```

#### output

```
1,0,0
1,0,0
0,0,0
0,0,0
0,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
```

Or here's a way using the [`Bit::Vector`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bit::Vector) which produces the same result

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Bit::Vector;

for my $val ( qw/ 02 02 00 00 00 01 01 08 08 08 / ) {

    my $vec = Bit::Vector->new_Hex(8, $val);

    my $torR = $vec->Chunk_Read(2, 0) ? 1 : 0;
    my $torY = $vec->Chunk_Read(1, 2) ? 1 : 0;
    my $torG = $vec->Chunk_Read(1, 3) ? 1 : 0;

    print "$torR,$torY,$torG\n";
}
```